# Crystal Reports 12.1: How to print on report, db server IP and datasource name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, crystal-reports, datasource

i-net Clear Reports Designer 12.1.232 on Win 7 connects to Postgre  SQL server

We have 2 Postgre SQL servers: a test and production. On each are several databases. I want to print the IP of the db server, and the datasource name (as specified in Crystal Reports Database Wizard) on my report. How do I do that?

I'm new to Crystal Reports but I'm familiar with programming. Which means I have no knowledge of CR objects, or CR specific things.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can query the v$database table to get some of this information. For Postgres, you can try the pg_stat_activity view and look at column datname for name of the database. IP address of the db server is more complicated, since multiple IPs exist for any single server depending on your point of reference.